# Tilemap.HasTile() always returns false for the top layer of tilemap ONLY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a building game, where you can build anywhere that there is no builds and touching the ground. Here is my code

```
private void Update()
{

    if (buildMode)
    {
        playerScript.enabled = false;
        Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            buildOverlay.ClearAllTiles();
            Vector3Int selectedTile = buildOverlay.WorldToCell(point);
            selectedTile.z = 0;
            if (Vector3.Distance(GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position, selectedTile) < buildDistance)
            {
                //BoundsInt bounds = collidableTilemap.cellBounds;
                //TileBase[] allTiles = collidableTilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);

                //for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++)
                //{
                //    for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++)
                //    {
                //        TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
                //        Debug.Log(collidableTilemap.HasTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0)));

                //        if (collidableTilemap.HasTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0)))
                //        {
                //            buildOverlay.SetTile(selectedTile, notplaceable);
                //        }
                //        else
                //        {
                //          buildOverlay.SetTile(selectedTile, placeable);

                //        }
                //    }
                //}
                selectedTile.z = 0;
                Debug.Log(selectedTile);
                Debug.Log(collidableTilemap.HasTile(selectedTile));
                if (!collidableTilemap.HasTile(selectedTile))
                {
                    buildOverlay.SetTile(selectedTile, placeable);
                }
                else
                {
                    buildOverlay.SetTile(selectedTile, notplaceable);
                }



            }




        }
        else
        {
            playerScript.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does so far is turn off the ability to move and check for an overlapping tile. I currently have the variable `buildDistance` set to infinity, so thats not the problem.

Here are some images:

[image: works under the first layer]

[image: it thinks the first layer isn't there]

Unity thinks that the first layer is not there. Here is the scene view to prove that those blocks are in the same tilemap:

[image: they are in same tilemap]

This code is supposed to see if a tile exists in the coordinates where the player wants to place. It works fine except for the first layer. Please help!

I'm pretty new to Unity so don't mind my noob mistakes. Thanks!

**[EDIT]:** I've changed my terrain a bit, and realized a couple new things:

This block is red

[image: I don't know why this is red]

This block is green.

[image: Why is this green????]

I can not build anywhere on this row, except for when the stone ends:

[image]

I can build here:

[image: WHAT IS GOING ON]

WHAT IS GOING ON!!!!!????!!???

Comment: Does this happen to tiles on the far left or right edge of the tilemap too, or just the top layer?
And are you allowed to place a tile on the first blank line below the ground?

Comment: @Jake I've updated my question for the information you asked. What is going on!!??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically it is 1 unit off of the y axis, so simply subtract 1 y unit.

Replace this line:

`if (!collidableTilemap.HasTile(selectedTile)`

with

`if (!collidableTilemap.HasTile(selectedTile - new Vector3Int(0, 1, 0)))`

This will basically negate the offset effect that Unity puts on tilemaps from flooring.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! THIS HELPED SO MUCH! I'VE BEEN STUCK ON THIS FOR DAYS!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for certain but It seems that the conversion from world space to grid coordinate is off-by-one at least in the y dimension and i would guess in the x direction also.
I believe the best candidate for the bug is this line here

```
Vector3Int selectedTile = buildOverlay.WorldToCell(point);
```

This kind of casting from `float` to `int` actually won't round the number but will instead floor it. Unity often places it's tilemaps so tiles are 0.5m misaligned with the world grid and because of this flooring the position might be causing these problems.
I would suggest trying

```
Vector3Int selectedTile = buildOverlay.WorldToCell(Vector3Int.RoundToInt(point))
```

or if that does not help you could try the uglier

```
Vector3Int selectedTile = buildOverlay.WorldToCell(point+Vector3.one*0.5f);
```

*(if this still doesn't work you could ommit the 0.5f)*

Not the prettiest of solutions but I think this is where your problem is I'd have a play about with it.

Comment: you may have to subtract instead of adding depending on the direction here

Comment: Will try today, it's crazy how you have so much reputation and you are a new contributor! I will let you know if it works

Comment: @CoderDude ahah i just asked a sightly popular question

Comment: so I tried all of your suggestions, all it did was move where the tile went, forexample one tile left and up of where i clicked. Any ideas on how to shift the tilemap?